# Index of next occurring record

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table

I have a sample dataset of the trajectory of one bike.   My objective is to figure out, on average, the amount of time that lapses in between visits to station B.

So far, I have been able to simply order the dataset with:

```
test[order(test$starttime, decreasing = FALSE),]
```

and find the row index of where `start_station` and `end_station` equal B.

```
 which(test$start_station == 'B')
 which(test$end_station == 'B')
```

The next part is where I run into trouble.  In order to calculate the time that lapses in between when the bike is at Station B, we must take the `difftime()` between where `start_station = "B"` (bike leaves) and the **next occurring record**  where `end_station= "B"`,  *even if* the record happens to be in the same row (see row 6).

Using the dataset below, we know that the bike spent 510 minutes between `7:30:00` and `16:00:00` outside of Station B, 30 minutes between `18:00:00` and `18:30:00` outside of Station B, and 210 minutes between `19:00:00` and `22:30:00` outside of Station B, which averages to `250 minutes.`

How would one reproduce this output in R using `difftime()`?

```
> test
   bikeid start_station           starttime end_station             endtime
1       1             A 2017-09-25 01:00:00           B 2017-09-25 01:30:00
2       1             B 2017-09-25 07:30:00           C 2017-09-25 08:00:00
3       1             C 2017-09-25 10:00:00           A 2017-09-25 10:30:00
4       1             A 2017-09-25 13:00:00           C 2017-09-25 13:30:00
5       1             C 2017-09-25 15:30:00           B 2017-09-25 16:00:00
6       1             B 2017-09-25 18:00:00           B 2017-09-25 18:30:00
7       1             B 2017-09-25 19:00:00           A 2017-09-25 19:30:00
8       1             А 2017-09-25 20:00:00           C 2017-09-25 20:30:00
9       1             C 2017-09-25 22:00:00           B 2017-09-25 22:30:00
10      1             B 2017-09-25 23:00:00           C 2017-09-25 23:30:00
```

Here is the sample data:

```
> dput(test)
structure(list(bikeid = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), start_station = c("A", 
"B", "C", "A", "C", "B", "B", "А", "C", "B"), starttime = structure(c(1506315600, 
1506339000, 1506348000, 1506358800, 1506367800, 1506376800, 1506380400, 
1506384000, 1506391200, 1506394800), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"
), tzone = ""), end_station = c("B", "C", "A", "C", "B", "B", 
"A", "C", "B", "C"), endtime = structure(c(1506317400, 1506340800, 
1506349800, 1506360600, 1506369600, 1506378600, 1506382200, 1506385800, 
1506393000, 1506396600), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "")), .Names = c("bikeid", 
"start_station", "starttime", "end_station", "endtime"), row.names = c(NA, 
-10L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: First step would be transforming to long format, something like `library(data.table); mtest = melt(setDT(test), id="bikeid", meas = patterns("_station", "time"), 
      variable.name = "event", value.name = c("station", "time"));
    mtest[.(factor(1:2), c("start", "end")), on=.(event), event := i.V2];
    setkey(mtest, bikeid, time)`, but I'm not sure the best way after that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will calculate the difference as asked in the order it occurs, but does not append it to the `data.frame`

```
lapply(df1$starttime[df1$start_station == "B"], function(x, et) difftime(et[x < et][1], x, units = "mins"), et = df1$endtime[df1$end_station == "B"])

[[1]]
Time difference of 510 mins

[[2]]
Time difference of 30 mins

[[3]]
Time difference of 210 mins

[[4]]
Time difference of NA mins
```

To calculate the average time:

```
v1 <- sapply(df1$starttime[df1$start_station == "B"], function(x, et) difftime(et[x < et][1], x, units = "mins"), et = df1$endtime[df1$end_station == "B"])
mean(v1, na.rm = TRUE)

[1] 250
```

Comment: Thanks, this method works.  Could you explain briefly how `function(x, et)` works?

Comment: `lapply` allows multiple arguments to be passed to the function.  The value for `x` is the `starttime` while `et` is the additional parameter that is defined after the function.  This is so that the parameter is only defined once, but can be used twice in the function.

Answer (score 1):

Another possibility:

```
library(data.table)
d <- setDT(test)[ , {
  start = starttime[start_station == "B"]
  end = endtime[end_station == "B"]
  .(start = start, end = end, duration = difftime(end, start, units = "min"))
}
, by = .(trip = cumsum(start_station == "B"))]
d
#    trip               start                 end duration
# 1:    0                <NA> 2017-09-25 01:30:00  NA mins
# 2:    1 2017-09-25 07:30:00 2017-09-25 16:00:00 510 mins
# 3:    2 2017-09-25 18:00:00 2017-09-25 18:30:00  30 mins
# 4:    3 2017-09-25 19:00:00 2017-09-25 22:30:00 210 mins
# 5:    4 2017-09-25 23:00:00                <NA>  NA mins


d[ , mean(duration, na.rm = TRUE)]
# Time difference of 250 mins

# or
d[ , mean(as.integer(duration), na.rm = TRUE)]
# [1] 250
```

---

The data is grouped by a counter which increases by 1 each time a bike starts  from "B" (`by = cumsum(start_station == "B")`).